# Program crash sequence sorting program

Tags: c++, crash

After finishing with the fixing the errors I ran the program and it crashed.Tried fixing the program for a while but couldn't.The program is about the sequence and sorting.The compiler is devcpp.Seems not quite to be a stack overflow. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void selectionSort(int *, int);

int main()
{
    int N;
    int a[ N ];

    cout << "\n Enter the length of sequence:";
    cin >> N;

    for (int i = 0; i < N && i < 5; ++i)
    {
        a[ N ] = rand() % 1000000 + 0;
        srand(time(0));
        cout << "Random sequence";
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            cout << setw(4) << a[i];
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Sorted sequence";
    selectionSort(a, N);
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        cout << setw(4) << a[j];
    cout << endl;
    getch();
}

void selectionSort(int *array, int N)
{
    int temp, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && array [j - 1] > array [j])
        {
            temp = array [j];
            array[j] = array [j - 1];
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your indentation is just ugly.

Comment: @ogzd new user may not be fully aware of how to indent their questions; I guess this is the whole point of edition and editors.

Comment: This is indeed very hard to read. What is the exact error? What platform are you using? What does gdb say? As far as I can tell, devcpp is an IDE, not a compiler.

Comment: @Rubens, that's why I have pointed it out.

Comment: 'After finishing with the fixing the errors I ran the program and it crashed' - this is normal. It's why debuggers exist.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a array with a variable `N` size.
Use this insted:

```
int *a = new int[N];
// ...
delete [] a;
```

Second problem is `a[N] = ...` that is access to an element which is doesn't exist.

Also, It's better to put `srand(time(0));` at the beginning of your code, not it the loop.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    int N;
    cout << "\n Enter the length of sequence:";
    cin >> N;

    int *a = new int[N]; // If you compiler support you can: int a[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        a[ i ] = rand() % 1000 + 0;
    }

    cout << "Random sequence";
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        cout << setw(4) << a[j];
    cout << endl;


    cout << "Sorted sequence";
    selectionSort(a, N);
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        cout << setw(4) << a[j];
    cout << endl;
    getch();

    delete [] a; // If you use pointer version
}
```

Comment: Kind of... They are called Variable Length Arrays, and quite a few C++ compilers support them since it is valid C. C++ may introduce it before the end of the decade, though I hope they dont! Anyway, if the compiler didn't support it, it would error out at compile time, not at runtime. Edit: of course, N should be initialized either way.

Comment: Down vote still stands, as you shouldn't recommend new/delete to beginners; vectors ftw.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: How do you absolutely sure new/delete shouldn't teach to a beginner? since all C++ books first teach them arrays and pointers and then introduce them classes and finally show them STLs.

Comment: OK. +1 after the edit. I agree too that vector can be easier to use (but harder to understand) and have to be teached first, but I’m also agree that in practice all the beginner need to know the basic of pointer-array-new-delete, just because that is what the books and courses teach. We are all waiting for a new good book or course.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access memory that you do not own.

```
 int N;
 int a[ N ];
```

You are declaring N and then defining your array with it, but at that point in time it has yet to be initialized.  Then when you try to write to the spot in memory, it seg faults.

Comment: Who says that `N == 0` at that point? I think it's uninitialized, meaning it could have *any* value.